# How do I give the basket its exact shape, for a physics body, it is an image?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

```
basket.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/8)
        basket.size.height = 50
        basket.size.width = 75
        basket.name = "basketNode"
        basket.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: basket.size)
        basket.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        basket.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = basketCategory
        basket.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.addChild(basket)
```

So currently, balls are falling from top of the screen, the players job is to catch them in the basket, for it to fall into the basket, I need it to have the exact shape of the basket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `init(texture:size:)` to create an `SKPhysicsBody` that matches the texture used by the basket. Here's an example:

```
let basket = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "basket")
basket.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: basket.texture!, size: basket.size)
// Do the rest of the setup.
```

In the example above I'm force unwrapping the `basket`'s `texture` property because I know it's not `nil` since I used `init(imageNamed:)` to initialise the `basket`.

Comment: Thank but can you please expand as I am new to swift and have looked at the documentation, but is the texture the image or the spriteNode